# File preview in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, preview

I want to implement file preview for files in my ASP.NET MVC3 application.

I need to create preview for multiple type of files in my MVC project.
Files includes: pdf, doc, docx, xsl, scv, txt, img, png, rtf, csv etc

My idea is to create class for each file type and render any of those files into set of images files that will be displayed to the user.

The solution needs to be HTML + Javascript only.

Any ideas what would be the best solution?

Comment: That seems like an extreme amount of work for a relatively small payoff. Why not just let the user download the file, and have a simple title-description for each document? Is the preview some kind of a protection method before the actual file can be downloaded?

Comment: Aspose and others create libraries that can be used in .NET to parse files (and thus, indirectly, create previews). HTML + Javascript only... I don't think that will happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to use the approach to load any file 
create pdf and from pdf to img.
I know its long process but its the best I could think of.